# How do I get Hazmat Gauntlets?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I landed on a planet and found an exotic element on.  However, to my surprise, it wasn't something you mine like the majority of the elements in the game. Instead, you need to walk up to it and pick it up.  But to pick it up, I need Hazmat Gauntlets.  How do I get these?

Comment: Can this be tagged with `foundation-update`?

Comment: Does that tag exist?

Comment: Someone with a high enough rep should be able to create it., If not, perhaps adding it to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over time, the way Hazmat Gauntlets are created has changed.

**Currently, you will need to:**

- Obtain their blueprint.

  - You can obtain their blueprint via the [Exosuit Upgrade Merchant](https://nomanssky.fandom.com/wiki/Haz-Mat_Gauntlet#Source) on the [Space Anomaly](https://nomanssky.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Anomaly).
- Craft them using 50 chromatic metal and 20 sodium nitrate.

Answer (score 9):

From [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/4/154642447916866017/), it looks like you'll need an armourer at your base, as that is who will give you the blueprints for them:

> Build the specialist terminals at your base, then staff them. 
>   One of them is a weapons terminal that needs you to find an armourer.
>   The armourer gives you a mini quest to get the plans for the Haz-Mat gloves.

Comment: Ugh this new update... it's like they are making up for something. I've still yet to get a base built.

Comment: @TimmyJim It's almost like we paid $60 for an Early Access game... ;)